# Linux Delete Files Older Than and the Same Time Smaller Than

Tags: linux, find

I use this command to delete MP3 files older than 90 days.

```
find MP3/ -type f -name "*.mp3" -mtime +90 -delete
```

I want to make it delete those older than 3 days but with file size less than 100KB.

How to write the arguments for `< 100KB` and is `-size` good to go or should I use something else as as far as I know the file size itself is different that the size on the disk...

```
find MP3/ -type f -name "*.mp3" -mtime +3 -size xxx -delete
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `+` and `-` signs with `size`, just as with `mtime`, so simply use `size -100k`.